# Is there a relationship between $\arctan(x/y)$ and $-\arctan(y/x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a relationship between $\arctan(x/y)$ and $\arctan(y/x)$?

In my calculations my final result is $\arctan(H/L)-\arctan(L/H)$ where $H$ and $L$ are just numbers. I'm wondering if there is any way I can combine them or if I'm just stuck with what I have.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a minus in between? I don't think there is a relation, at least not a nice one I am aware off. With a plus in between (obviously) there is...

Comment: Thanks, I do know the obvious relation with positive signs. That was my first reaction to check if I made a sign error, but I don't see the minus sign going away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation is $\arctan(t) = \pi/2 -  \arctan(1/t) $ if $t > 0$, so (assuming $H,L>0$) $\arctan(H/L) - \arctan(L/H) = 2 \arctan(H/L) - \pi/2$.

Comment: Is there any way for H/L to vanish

Comment: Sure, just take $H=0$.

Comment: I know $H>0$ though

Comment: Well then, $H/L$ won't vanish!

Answer (score 0):

$$ arctan ( x/y) - (- arctan ( y/x)) = \pi/2 $$

Comment: That's not the equation I wrote initially